# How to declare an object from a condition and make it available through the rest of the function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have two classes, both with the same function names that do similar things based on user input. I need to do something like this.

```
if (myapp.advanced == true)
    class1 a;
else
    class2 a;
```

But since a is declared from inside the if, it's not available in the next line. How do fix the above condition?

```
 a.something();
```

Comment: Is the value of `myapp.advanced` known at compile-time?

Comment: @Steve: Nope, it's set by the user when the program is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these types are related, use a common base class and do this:

```
const base& a = (myapp.advanced == true) ? static_cast<base&>(class1())
                                         : class2();
a.something();
a.some_other_thing();
a.yet_another_thing();
```

Temporaries bound to a `const` reference have their lifetimes extended until the end of the reference's lifetime, so this is safe. However, such hackery wouldn't be necessary (and you can do away with the `const`, if you need to modify the object) if you separated the concerns ***object creation*** and ***object using*** into different functions:

```
void do_something(base& obj)
{
  obj.something();
  obj.some_other_thing();
  obj.yet_another_thing();
}

if (myapp.advanced == true) {
    class1 a;
    do_something(a);
} else {
    class2 a;
    do_something(a);
}
```

If the types are unrelated, you could still do this by turning `do_something()` into a function templates:

```
template< class T >
void do_something(T& obj)
{
  obj.something();
  obj.some_other_thing();
  obj.yet_another_thing();
}

if (myapp.advanced == true) {
    class1 a;
    do_something(a);
} else {
    class2 a;
    do_something(a);
}
```

Comment: @sbi: Yes, I noticed after I commented that you'd added a different one, no worries. Btw, the ternary expression won't compile without a cast, because `class1()` and `class2()` don't have the same type. One of them needs to be cast to `const base&`.

Comment: @sgolodetz: You're right, thanks for pointing this out! I fixed it.

Comment: One other issue, incidentally, is that the first method only works if it's ok for the objects to be `const` -- since you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. But if it's fine for them to be `const`, then this is a good way of going about things.

Comment: @sgolodetz: You're right about that, too. I'm somewhat frustrated, because the `const` issue was what made me come up with the second method in the first place, but then I completely blew this. `<sigh>` Maybe I should learn to like coffee.

Comment: @sbi: Sorry, not meaning to get at you -- I actually liked your answer, just wanted to point out a couple of things I'd spotted.

Comment: @sgolodetz: No no no, I was frustrated about me, not about you.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I can think of:

1) Make class1 and class2 derive from some base class `classB`, then do:

```
shared_ptr<classB> a;
if(myapp.advanced == true) a.reset(new class1);
else a.reset(new class2);
a->something();
```

2) Write a template function:

```
template <typename T> void do_something(T& t)
{
  t.something();
}

...

if(myapp.advanced)
{
  class1 a;
  do_something(a);
}
else
{
  class2 a;
  do_something(a);
}
```

Note that the second approach is more suitable if you can't change `class1` and `class2` to add the base class. I'm also assuming that the bit inside `do_something` is more complicated than just calling `something()` on the object in question -- otherwise you could just call it directly!

EDIT: Just to clarify, the second approach doesn't make it available throughout the rest of the function in question -- it adds a new function in which it's available instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your coding logic implies that Class1 and Class2 have something in common. Express this in code by having them derive from a common base class.
Then use a base class pointer to hold instances of the derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting function something() as pure virtual to base class and inherit class1 and class2 from it.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void something() = 0;
    virtual ~Base(){}; // since we use Base class pointer the destructor should be virtual
};

class class1 : public Base
{
public:
    void something(){ //do stuff
    }
};
class class2 : public Base
{
public:
    void something(){ //do other stuff
    }
};
```

Here's a sample of usage of this technique:

```
int main()
{    
    Base* a = NULL;

    if (myapp.advanced == true)
        a = new class1();
    else
        a = new class2();

    a->something();

    // when the instance is not needed anymore destroy it.
    delete a;
}
```

Like Fred Nurk mentioned in the comments there's other alternatives for using `delete` operator - auto_ptr, different boost smart pointers. They're widely used by many people (including myself) making it easier to control the life of objects created with `new`.

Another edit following OP's comment:
Don't forget to put multiple inclusion protection macro in your headers

```
#ifndef _SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE_
#define _SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE_

// header body goes here

#endif
```

to avoid multiple including (direct or indirect) of your headers into one cpp.

Comment: Don't forget to delete a. :-) If you don't want a base class you could do the same but with two pointers, and then call something via whichever is non-NULL.

Comment: +1, this seems to be a prime candidate for an interface + 2 concrete implementations.

Comment: Might want to make `Base::something()`, `class1::something()` and `class2::something()` public and add a virtual destructor to `Base`.

Comment: @Leo Davidson deleting a seems to be obvious, but you're right - I added it :)

Comment: Can this be done if the two classes are declared from separate header files or should I put them both in the same file?

Comment: @thorvald they can be in separate headers, but then they should both include the header with the base class declaration

Comment: Don't use delete, use auto_ptr, unique_ptr, scoped_ptr, or alternatives.

Comment: This introduces dynamically allocated objects without knowing whether they are really needed and then propagates manual memory management. Sorry, but that's a `-1` from me.

Comment: @sbi I'm just demonstrating the technique with base class, answering the question. Not going to rewrite OP's application...

Comment: @Dimitry: There's nothing about manually managing dynamic objects in the OP's question. _You_ introduced `new` to this, and _your_ answer shows how to do this manually. That's why I down-voted your answer. Oh, and that base class thing doesn't necessarily need a dynamic object (see my answer).

Comment: @sbi I took Fred's comment into consideration and mentioned in the answer that there are other options except delete. I never said dynamic object is a must. It could be used though for simple example like this hopefully making the idea of base class clearer.

Comment: @thorvald see another edit, probably helping to solve this problem.

Comment: Why is something() = 0 and not some other number? What does that mean?

Comment: @thorvald: The "= 0" means it is pure, which can only be applied to virtuals, giving pure virtuals.  Pure virtuals make a type abstract and generally indicate it is not defined (and thus cannot be directly called).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this, but without further info I would probably advice you to do this:

I suppose the classes have common ancestor called Base

```
Base* a;
if (myapp.advanced == true)
    a = new class1();
else
    a = new class2();
```

Of course you must not forget to issue a `delete` after you no longer need it or use a smart pointer.

If you find yourself repeating this if-else statement often, this procedure might be better of wrapped in some sort of function or factory class, but it all depends on the circumstances.

Comment: You mean `a = new class2;` for the else branch :)